# print a line for the firstt time and then every 30 minutes

Tags: java, date, for-loop, iteration

I have a below method which will be called every one minute from background thread.

```
public void testMethod() {
    // some other code

    System.out.println("hello")

    // some other code
}
```

Now every one minute, `hello` line will get printed out. Is there any way, by which hello line should get printed for the first time and then after every half an hour (it doesn't have to be exact half an hour) once testMethod is invoked by background thread. I don't want to use any executors or timer class.

I just don't want my hello line gets printed out every one minute. In the starting it should print once and then every 30-35 minutes is fine. Is there any other way to do this without using Timer or Executors? Can we not use current time and do some mod check?

I want all other code in testMethod to get executed every one minute so I cannot sleep or anything. I just need to have some random check by which we can decide whether to print hello or not. I just don't want to print hello every one minute.

Comment: And when would you want your program to stop printing? Or do you want this to run without an endtime?

Comment: yes just keep running as it is. Whenever my background thread that calls testMethod stops, it will get stop eventually.

Comment: Please explain why you can't use a timer. The situation you're describing *screams* timer; why go against the force?

Comment: @user1950349, I have updated my answer based on your updated question and comments

Answer (score 3):

Have a static member variable for stoping the loop

```
private static boolean isTrue = true;

public static boolean getIsTrue() {
    return isTrue;
}

public static void setIsTrue(boolean test) {
    YourClass.isTrue = test;
}
```

Your program should be

```
    System.out.println("hello");
    Thread printText = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            while(getIsTrue()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30*60*1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("hello");
            }
        }
    };
    printText.start();
```

When you want to stop your loop

```
public void testMethod() {
    setIsTrue(false);
}
```

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, Recheck your downvote, my updated answer executes the printing section in a different thread so that the rest of the code can get executed. Based on the question, I think my response is valid.

Comment: I've restored the vote now. Ultimately, I think sleeping isn't superior to other options but OP has some questionable requirements so I won't hold that against you.

Comment: Yup, agreed. I originally wanted to suggest `Scheduler`

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are calling it from a background thread you can just use an infinite loop or a finite loop with a `Thread.sleep(30*60*1000)` into it

If you want it to loop infinitely

```
public void testMethod() {
    (new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
            while(true){
                long currentUnixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
                if ((currentUnixTime - unixTime)>=30*60){
                    System.out.println("hello");
                    unixTime = currentUnixTime;
                }
            }
        }
   }).start();
}
```

This implementation will waste a lot a your cpu cycle, you can use the same logic to implement a finite one.

Comment: I dont want to keep waiting for 30 minutes... I want all other things in testMethod to work as it is.. Just some random check by which we will decide whether to  print hello or not. If condition doesn't met, then do other stuffs in testMethod

Comment: @user1950349 then invoke this method from another background thread dedicated to this work only

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the Question is not asking about sleeping for a half hour. The Question says that part of a method should be skipped unless at least a half hour has elapsed.

In Java 8 and later you should be using the java.time framework for date-time work. All we need is the `Instant` class which represents a moment on the timeline in UTC.

Store the next time the extra code needs to be executed in a variable of type `java.time.Instant`. Initialize to a moment ago so the extra code will run on first time through.

```
Instant instantWhenDue = Instant.now().minusSeconds( 1 );
```

In your method add a test to see if the current moment is past our due time.

```
// do some stuff…
if ( Instant.now().isAfter( instantWhenDue ) ) {
    // do your extra work like say Hello…
    // Set when due to run again.
    instantWhenDue = Instant.now().plusMinutes( 30 );
}
// do other stuff…
```